# img src="" not showing image

Tags: html

I am writing a very basic webpage, while doing so I am trying to put an image on one of the pages. I am using HTML and this is what I have so far:

```
 <div id ="div4"><img src="file:///Users/me/Documents/image.jpg" 
width="460" height="460"/></div>
```

I am using Brackets editor and when I use the preview option, the image shows up blank with a symbol in the top left corner. If you can let me know what i am doing wrong that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: if `image.jpg` is in the same folder as your `HTML` page, then you can use a relative path to load the image: `<img src="./image.jpg" />`

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers block access to any `file://` URL's if the page is being loaded over any other protocol such as `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something it wrong with the filepath.

If the img is in the same file as the html document, use this

```
<img src="image.jpg">
```

If the img is in a different folder, use `../` to go back from the current folder like this

```
<img src="../differentfolder/image.jpg">
```

(As well, in brackets you can hover over the img filepath in the code to display a preview of the image. If the filepath is correct, the image should appear)

Answer (score 0):

If `image.jpg` is in the same folder as your `HTML` page, then you can use a relative path to load the image: `<img src="./image.jpg" />`

For example, if file structure is like this:

```
parent folder
 |
 +- index.html
    image.jpg
```

Of course, you can adjust the path according to the image's location in relation to the `HTML` page.